# DirectoryNotFoundException with XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I am working on a process to deploy Sharepoint Dashboards to a Sharepoint server. The dashboard file is a .DDWX, but its an XML file. What I do is read in this XML file, and serialize it into the object that the XML represents. This is done here

```
var model = Deserialize<ScorecardModel>(File.ReadAllText(workspaceFile));
```

When I run the application (its just an exe file) on sharepoint server, I get the following error

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of path 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Temp\2\wnkzh25x.tmp'

It seems this gets thrown from within the

> System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)

method. Is there something I am missing here? It works completely fine on my local machine as well as other servers, but not this one. Is there an Assembly that needs to be added somewhere?

EDIT::::

After some more digging, this is the line that is failing

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

T in this case is of type Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.DesignerWorkspace.ScorecardModel (which the DLL is included in the solution). Do I need to register this assembly?

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue in that the account running Sharepoint cannot read your profile folder.

Comment: I am logged onto the box, and running the exe from the desktop. How would the logged in user not have permissions to write to it's own profile folder.

Comment: I dont know if it helps but do you use the type you use as T somewhere? In the past I had a problem that I referenced a DLL but that DLL was not deployed. The problem was, that nothing of the DLL was directly used. After I create one instance of a object of this DLL the DLL was deployed correctly.

Comment: I load the XML file to a custom type, and make changes to some XPaths of that type dynamically (in theory, just testing at the moment), so without it being super hacky I need the T :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, and am embarrassed to report it was a .Net versioning issue. I wrote the app in 4.5 and the server had 4.0 on it. Installing 4.5 fixed the issue.